# About android mobile application development?

Tags: android

Android mobile application development is the J2ME Application.I need to know about it? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I can't really understand your question. If you want to know if Android Applications are developed in J2ME the answer is no. You code your applications in core Java and you have to use the Android API for creating your user interface and to react to user input.

If you already have an J2ME App and want to run/convert it to Android have a look at: [Android J2ME Runner](http://www.netmite.com/android/)

Comment: +1 for making an attempt at helping the guy... Instead of just marking him down.

Answer (score 0):

J2ME application is different from Android application development. Android has its own set of SDK's and API's like J2ME.

In short Android is architecturally different than J2ME. It has its own Virtual machine called Dalvik and the fundamental app structure differs as well. If you have written an application in J2ME you have to Port it using Android API's